# Issues with Popup - JSF1.2

Tags: jsf-1.2, trinidad

I have a parent screen with a link to popup so when i open and close the popup 10 times and try to save the data on parent screen, i see the parent screen's view is lost.

I have a configuration in the web.xml for the maximum JSF views that can be stored in the session as 10 and the state_saving_method is server(i cannot change this to client due to arch decision)

So is there is a way to remove the view from session or a way to prevent the parent screen's view from getting lost?

Thanks in advance

Comment: And i dont want to increase the maximum views in the session aswell

Comment: Any thoughts on this?